# Inherit constructors via using but make it out-of-line

Tags: c++, constructor-inheritance

Consider the following short but multifile [example](https://wandbox.org/permlink/RgliBcvlHT7kf3P2):

```
// ************************** unit.h **************************
#pragma once

#include <memory>

struct S;

struct B {
    B(int) {};
    virtual ~B() {};
};

struct D : B {
   D(int);
   ~D() override;
   std::unique_ptr<S> p;
};

// ************************** unit.cpp **************************
#include "unit.h"

struct S {};

D::D(int i) : B(i) {}

D::~D() = default; 

// ************************** prog.cc **************************
#include "unit.h"

int main()
{
    D d(42);
}
```

There are two classes with inheritance: base `B` and derived `D`. `D` class contains a `unique_ptr` member definition with only declared class `S`. To make this scheme work I need to define both constructor and destructor of class `D` out-of-line (i.e. implemented in *unit.cpp*, where the full definition of `S` is visible).

The question: is it possible to use the `using B::B;` declaration in the `D` class inherit the `B`'s constructors to prevent writing manually `D::D(int i) : B(i) {}`, but make this inheritance out-of-line in order to prevent [compilation error](https://wandbox.org/permlink/9phP5Lv6XyabwlEz)?

> ```
> error: invalid application of 'sizeof' to an incomplete type 'S'
> ```

Comment: @KamilCuk my question is about constructor inheritance via `using`, not about requirement for `unique_ptr` template.

Answer (score 2):

> is it possible to use the using `B::B;` declaration in the `D` class inherit the `B`'s constructors to prevent writing manually `D::D(int i) : B(i) {}`

It is possible.

Along with the forward declaration of `struct S` also declare its deleter:

```
struct S;

struct SDeleter { void operator()(S*) const; }; // Defined elsewhere.
```

And then:

```
struct D : B {
   using B::B;
   std::unique_ptr<S, SDeleter> p;
};
```

The definition of `void SDeleter::operator()(S*) const` must be provided in another translation unit (.cc) that has access to the definition of `S`.

Comment: Nice. But this variant looks more prolix than original version.